# Most effective method to use parallel computing on different architectures

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, mpi, grand-central-dispatch

I am planning to write something to take advantages of the many devices that I have at home.

Basically my aim is to use the laptop to execute calculations, and also to use my main desktop computer to add more power (and finish the task quicker). I work with cellular simulation and chemical interactions, so to me would be great to take advantage of all that I have available at home.

I am using mainly OSX, so I need something that may work with that OS. I can code in objective-C, C and C++.

I am aware of GCD, OpenCL and MPI, but I am not sure which way to go.

I was planning to not use the full power of my desktop but only some of the available cores (in this way I can continue to work on the desktop doing other tasks that are not so resource intensive). In particular I would love to use the graphic card power (it is an ATI card, so no CUDA), since all that I do mainly is spreadsheet, word and coding with Xcode, and the graphic card resources are basically unused in that scenario.

Is there a specific set of libraries or API, among the aforementioned 3, that would allow me to selectively route tasks, and use resources on another machine without leaving the control totally to the compiler? I've heard that GCD is great but it has very limited control on where the blocks are executed, while MPI is on the other side of the spectrum....OpenCL seems to be in the middle.

Before diving in one of these technologies I would like to know which one would most likely suit my needs; I am sure that some other researcher has already used successfully parallel computing to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPI is more for scientific computing large scale many processors many nodes exc not for a weekend project, for what you describe I would suggest using OpenCl or any one the more distributed framework of AMQP protocol families, such as [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org) or rabbitMQ, or a combination of OpenCl and AMQP , or even simpler consider multithreading , i would suggest OpenMP for that. I'm not sure if you are looking for direct solvers or parallel functions but there are many that exist as well for gpu's and cpu's which you can find on the web

Comment: Thanks for the reply. BTW my project is not a "weekend project"; I am dealing with DNA exams and protein building all the time :) I just would like to use the resources available in a more efficient way. I will check these AMQP protocols, but from what I can see at first glance, they look more like facilitators for network sharing of tasks, instead than being a solution to actually code a program and effectively divide it in phases that can be processed on different CPU/GPU and then put together to give the final results. I will look further and see if they fit my needs.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to use both your desktop and laptop as compute nodes... and instead just work on getting your desktop cpu and gpu working together and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this question simply cannot be **meaningfully** answered as posed.  To be sure, I could toss out a collection of buzzwords describing various technologies to look at like GCD, OpenMPI, OpenCL, CUDA and any number of other technologies which allow one to run a single program on multiple cores, multiple programs on different cooperating computers, or a single program distributed across CPU and GPU, and it sounds like you know about a number of those already so I wouldn't even be adding much value in listing the buzzwords.

To simply toss out such terms without knowing the full specifics of the problem you're trying to solve, however, is a bit like saying that you know English, French and a little German so sure, by all means - mix them all together in a single paragraph without knowing anything about the target audience!   Similarly, you can parallelize a given computation in any number of ways, across any number of different processing elements, but whether that parallelization is actually a **win** or not is going to be entirely dependent on the nature of the algorithm, its data dependencies, how much computation is expected for each reasonable "work chunk", and whether it can be executed on a GPU with sufficient numeric precision, among many other factors.  The more complex the technology you choose, the more those factors matter and the greater the possibility that the resulting code will actually be **slower** than its single-threaded, single machine counterpart.  IPC overhead and data copying can, and frequently do, swamp all of the gains one might realize from trying to naively parallelize something and then add additional overhead on top of that, resulting in a net loss.  This is why engineers who can do this kind of work meaningfully and well are in such high demand. :)

Without knowing anything about your calculations, I would move in baby steps.  First try a simple multi-processor framework like GCD (which is already built in to OS X and requires no additional dependencies to use) and figure out how to factor your code such that it can effectively use all of the available cores on a single machine.  Once you've learned where the wins are (and if there even are any - if multi-threading isn't helping, multi-machine parallelization almost certainly won't either), try setting up several instances of the calculation on several machines with a simple IPC model that allows for distributing the work.  Having already factored your algorithm(s) for multiple threads, it should be comparatively straight-forward to further generalize the approach across multiple machines (though it bears noting that the two are NOT the same problem and either way you still want to use all the cores available on any of the given target machines, so the two challenges are both complimentary and orthogonal).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the problem of giving a reply based on a generic question like mine...sadly i am under NDA from my company so I cannot say exactly what we do; but my idea is to write something that can increase productivity and make my life easier, using all the devices that I have available.
As overview, I get DNA samples, and divide them looking for specific genes and then looking at the proteins; so my tasks involves rendering of molecules (graphic intensive tasks), floating point operations and DB access operations. That's why I thought to use one  among MPI or OpenCL.

Comment: The only problem with the baby steps approach is mainly the time: experimenting would take away time from my job...that's why I've asked the question here, hoping that someone that does this already can tell me "this works for this kind of tasks, and these kind of algorithms"; in this way I avoid to have to learn in parallel 3 different API (which does not allow to share code, so each one requires a new approach in coding the software), and just focus on one.

Comment: I can understand and sympathize with the constraints you're operating under, but even knowing you're doing DNA analysis doesn't much help.  If you look at a project in a similar problem space to yours, the Protein folding project at Stanford (http://folding.stanford.edu/English/HomePage) for example, you'll quickly realize that they have crafted a series of entirely custom solutions to distributing that particular problem on a wide variety of targets, from distributed CPU environments to the PS3 to GPUs, and there's very little off-the-shelf technology there.  You may be in the same position.

Comment: Indeed, I am aware of that project and it goes on a similar plane as my project. My objective thou is not to divide and scale the problem on N amount of devices, but just to divide it efficiently in a finite number of devices (which is less than 10). Would be great to have a solution ready to be implemented, but since I am starting from the design phase, I can adapt my procedures to the API, and that's why I was looking for a minimum of guidance about which API would be better to implement my application. At this point I think that I will go for OpenCL, and see if it fits my needs. Thanks!